# SimplePie Getting the urls of all feeds on a site

Tags: php, simplepie

I am trying to discover feeds based on an url.

```
    $this->simplepie->set_feed_url('http://bitelia.com');
    $this->simplepie->init();
    $this->simplepie->handle_content_type();
    var_dump($this->simplepie->subscribe_url());
    var_dump($this->simplepie->get_all_discovered_feeds());
```

There is a couple issues with this.  I am passing in a url (it is not a feed url) and I am hoping to discover feeds.

If there are feeds on the site, calling `subscribe_url()` returns the feed url, but if there are no feeds on the site `subscribe_url` just returns the url I passed in.  Additionally `get_all_discovered_feeds()` has not returned anything for me yet (just an empty array).

My question is: Is there a reliable way to get all feeds on the domain using SimpliePie? I appreciate your time.  Thank you.